# Chrome Creating issue for Intrapage link in Anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, google-chrome

I am having a unique issue which I never came across. In my Case when I use the `"#filterPop"` in the Url chrome is appending additional slash after / like : `"#/filterpop"`.

Can someone Suggest how to eliminte this behaviour ?

PS: I am using Angular JS but I am not using any Routing.

Thanks.

Comment: please post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set html mode like
`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` in app.js (main js) file
and set base tag in html file

```
<base href='/'>
```